# Couldn't find a saved dataset

Tags: r

```
model_one <-glm( 
  Survived ~ age_imputed,
  family = binomial(),
  data = train_imputed 
  )
logistic_cv1 <- cv.glm(train_imputed, model_1, cost, K=5)
logistic_cv1$delta
```

I'm trying to use k-fold cross-validation to measure our model's performance on data. So I used glm function but after I run the code, this error message pops up,

```
Error in cv.glm(train_imputed, model_1, cost, K = 5) : object 'model_1' not found
```

How to fix this problem? I found it weird I saved model_1 as a new variable. But I couldn't find its dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy:  your model in your code above is called `model_one`, but you call for `model_1` in your code.

Run this and it should work:

`logistic_cv1 <- cv.glm(train_imputed, model_one, cost, K=5)`

Comment: OMG I'm so stupid. Thank you!!!!

Comment: @Three_freeze cool! To help me get more points, could you accept my answer please (by up voting it). Thanks!